# ADODB.Recordset Debug.Prints are ignored

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, recordset

I am currently working on a project, where I am required to use SQL queries on excel sheets. For that reason I chose ADODB recordsets. However I have a problem because some code lines are simply ignored when the recordset is referenced.
The code in question is the following:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset

DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
sconnect = "Provide=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPath _
           & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
conn.Open sconnect


vSql = "SELECT AMOUNT, COUNT(AMOUNT) FROM [MU_v2#7$A1:F192] WHERE TBL = '12.0' AND ROWNAME = '30' AND COLNAME = '45'"
rs2.Open vSql, conn

Debug.Print("Hello")
Debug.Print("The value is: " & rs2(0))

If rs2(1) = 0 Then
    ws.Cells(1, 13).Value = "No entry found"
Else
    ws.Cells(1, 13).Value = rs2(0)
End If
rs2.Close
```

When I run this, I only get the line "Hello" then nothing from "The values is: X)

Comment: Does your code contain any error handling?  Have you tried [stepping through](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)?

Comment: Do you have an `On error` statement active? I assume your Sql is invalid or doesn't return any value and accessing the recordset throws an error

Comment: Thank you for your replies: @FunThomas: Actually I have no On error statement, so the code should run straight down.

Comment: @destination-data: I have just stepped through that particular lines of code and it executes the debug.print part but nothing else happens

Comment: After you step over the line `Debug.Print("The value is: " & rs2(0))` type this command into the immediate window: `? err.Description`.  Does it return anything?  After stepping over the debug print does the code move onto `If rs2(1) = 0 Then`?

Comment: @destination-data: It's in German, but it basically something along the lines of "An object, that matches the requested name cannot be found.". And yes, it jumps to `If rs2(1) = 0 Then` and then even goes in that If-case

Comment: Ok.  That means you do have an `On Error` statement somewhere, which is suppressing error messages.  Best to find and comment out while debugging.  Error handling is inherited.  So if sub a has it and calls sub b then so too does b.  If you rerun without you will probably find this line returns an error: `rs2.Open vSql, conn`.

Comment: @destination-data: Oh wow, you were right, I had a piece of code that was deleting existing filters and that was suppressing the error messages. Now I have a new error that I can continue research on! Thank you very much :)